# Merging and counting in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got two pandas dataframe with unique and non-unique words:

DataFrame 1:

```
Word Frequency Pos
Dance 10       INFN
Listen 5       INFN
```

And DataFrame 2:

```
Word Frequency Pos
Dance 15       INFN
Hear 5         INFN
```

So I need some how to merge these dataframes that rows like "dance" would have counted frequency from both dataframes, so output looks like this:

```
Word Frequency Pos
Dance 25       INFN
Hear  5         INFN
Listen 5      INFN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `concat` , then `groupby` with `sum`

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['Word','Pos'])['Frequency'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `append` and `groupby`:

```
df = df1.append(df2).groupby(['Word', 'Pos'], as_index=False).sum()
print(df)

     Word   Pos  Frequency
0   Dance  INFN         25
1    Hear  INFN          5
2  Listen  INFN          5
```